# How to find the integer numbers a, b, c, m, n satifying the following conditions and remove the empty sets in this results?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

How can I find the integer numbers `a, b, c, m,n` so that the funtion
`f[x]=(a x^2 + b x + c)/(m x + n)` with the equation
`D[f[x], x]] == 0` have two integer solutions `x1`, `x2` and the values `f[x1]` and `f[x2]` are also integer numbers?

I tried

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = (a x^2 + b x + c)/(m x + n);
x1 = (-a n - Sqrt[a c m^2 - a b m n + a^2 n^2])/(a m);
x2 = (-a n + Sqrt[a c m^2 - a b m n + a^2 n^2])/(a m);
list = Table[
  If[GCD[a, b, c] == 1 && GCD[m, n] == 1 && 
    a c m^2 - a b m n + a^2 n^2 > 0 && a n - b m  != 0 && 
    a (c m^2 - b m n + a n^2) > 0 && b^2 - 4 * a * c < 0 && 
    IntegerQ[x1] && IntegerQ[x2] && b c m n x1 x2 f[x1]* f[x2] != 0 &&
     IntegerQ[f[x1]] && 
    IntegerQ[f[x2]], {(a x^2 + b x  + c)/(m x + n), {x1, f[x1]}, {x2, 
     f[x2]}}, Nothing], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 10}, {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

How can I remove the empty sets in my results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = (a x^2 + b x + c)/(m x + n);
x1 = (-a n - Sqrt[a c m^2 - a b m n + a^2 n^2])/(a m);
x2 = (-a n + Sqrt[a c m^2 - a b m n + a^2 n^2])/(a m);
list = Table[
   If[GCD[a, b, c] == 1 && GCD[m, n] == 1 && 
     a c m^2 - a b m n + a^2 n^2 > 0 && a n - b m  != 0 && 
     a (c m^2 - b m n + a n^2) > 0 && b^2 - 4 * a * c < 0 && 
     IntegerQ[x1] && IntegerQ[x2] && b c m n x1 x2 f[x1]* f[x2] != 0 &&
      IntegerQ[f[x1]] && 
     IntegerQ[f[x2]], {(a x^2 + b x  + c)/(m x + n), {x1, f[x1]}, {x2,
       f[x2]}}, Nothing], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 
    10}, {n, 1, 10}];
Flatten[list, 4]
```

> {{(7 + x + x^2)/(2 + x), {-5, -9}, {1, 3}}, {(10 + x + x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-7, -13}, {1, 3}}, {(3 + 2 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-2, -1}, {1, 2}}, {(5 + 2 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -4}, {1, 4}}, {(7 + 2 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-3, -2}, {2, 3}}, {(7 + 2 x + x^2)/(
> 3 + 2 x), {-4, -3}, {1, 2}}, {(10 + 2 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-4, -6}, {2, 6}}, {(3 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -3}, {-1, 1}}, {(5 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 4 + x), {-7, -11}, {-1, 1}}, {(6 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -3}, {1, 5}}, {(6 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 5 + x), {-9, -15}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 6 + x), {-11, -19}, {-1, 1}}, {(8 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 7 + x), {-13, -23}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 8 + x), {-15, -27}, {-1, 1}}, {(10 + 3 x + x^2)/(
> 9 + x), {-17, -31}, {-1, 1}}, {(5 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -2}, {-1, 2}}, {(6 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 5 + 2 x), {-4, -2}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -2}, {1, 6}}, {(7 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-5, -6}, {-1, 2}}, {(8 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-3, -1}, {2, 4}}, {(8 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 7 + 2 x), {-6, -4}, {-1, 1}}, {(10 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 3 + 2 x), {-4, -2}, {1, 3}}, {(10 + 4 x + x^2)/(
> 9 + 2 x), {-8, -6}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 5 x + x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -1}, {-1, 3}}, {(7 + 5 x + x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-4, -3}, {-2, 1}}, {(8 + 5 x + x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -1}, {1, 7}}, {(8 + 5 x + x^2)/(
> 4 + x), {-6, -7}, {-2, 1}}, {(10 + 5 x + x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-5, -5}, {-1, 3}}, {(10 + 5 x + x^2)/(
> 6 + x), {-10, -15}, {-2, 1}}, {(10 + 6 x + x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-4, -2}, {-2, 2}}, {(7 + x + 2 x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -11}, {1, 5}}, {(5 + 2 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-2, -3}, {1, 3}}, {(9 + 3 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -9}, {1, 7}}, {(4 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -7}, {-1, 1}}, {(5 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-5, -15}, {-1, 1}}, {(6 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 4 + x), {-7, -23}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 5 + x), {-9, -31}, {-1, 1}}, {(8 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 6 + x), {-11, -39}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 7 + x), {-13, -47}, {-1, 1}}, {(10 + 5 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 8 + x), {-15, -55}, {-1, 1}}, {(5 + 6 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 3 + 2 x), {-2, -1}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 6 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-2, -1}, {1, 5}}, {(7 + 6 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 5 + 2 x), {-4, -5}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 6 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 7 + 2 x), {-6, -9}, {-1, 1}}, {(8 + 7 x + 2 x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -5}, {-1, 3}}, {(10 + x + 3 x^2)/(
> 1 + x), {-3, -17}, {1, 7}}, {(7 + 2 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-2, -5}, {1, 4}}, {(8 + 4 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-2, -4}, {1, 5}}, {(5 + 7 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -11}, {-1, 1}}, {(6 + 7 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-5, -23}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 7 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 4 + x), {-7, -35}, {-1, 1}}, {(8 + 7 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 5 + x), {-9, -47}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 7 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 6 + x), {-11, -59}, {-1, 1}}, {(10 + 7 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 7 + x), {-13, -71}, {-1, 1}}, {(6 + 8 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 3 + 2 x), {-2, -2}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 8 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -10}, {-1, 2}}, {(8 + 8 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 5 + 2 x), {-4, -8}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 8 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-5, -22}, {-1, 2}}, {(10 + 8 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 1 + 2 x), {-2, -2}, {1, 7}}, {(10 + 8 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 7 + 2 x), {-6, -14}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 10 x + 3 x^2)/(
> 3 + 2 x), {-2, -1}, {-1, 2}}, {(6 + 9 x + 4 x^2)/(
> 2 + x), {-3, -15}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 9 x + 4 x^2)/(
> 3 + x), {-5, -31}, {-1, 1}}, {(8 + 9 x + 4 x^2)/(
> 4 + x), {-7, -47}, {-1, 1}}, {(9 + 9 x + 4 x^2)/(
> 5 + x), {-9, -63}, {-1, 1}}, {(10 + 9 x + 4 x^2)/(
> 6 + x), {-11, -79}, {-1, 1}}, {(7 + 10 x + 4 x^2)/(
> 3 + 2 x), {-2, -3}, {-1, 1}}}

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
f[x_]:=(a x^2+b x+c)/(d x^2+e x+m);
FindInstance[{D[f[x1],x1]==0,D[f[x2],x2]==0,
  0<a<=1,0<b<=1,0<c<=1,0<d<=1,0<e<=1,0<m<=1,
  x1!=x2,Element[x1|x2,Integers]},{a,b,c,d,e,m,x1,x2}]
```

which finds an instance which seems to satisfy your conditions.

If you change all those <= to < then it finds a different solution.